# Best practice Symfony translation placeholder naming text vs. key

Tags: symfony, internationalization, symfony4

We are translating an existing Symfony4 application by extracting the texts with the translation component and additionally using php-translation/symfony-bundle

**We are unsure if it is better to use the existing texts as keys or insert placeholders.**

The advantage of using texts are:

- in the xlf file the source and target are side by side to use for a translator.
- the twig files still make sense for the designer without having to check the website
- it is clear what the placeholder is for
- it is extracted like this from the code, no manual error prone copy & paste

The disadvantages are:

- every time the original source is adapted we have an invalid key

How do you and your team handle this? 
And is the translation file part of your repository?

This link suggests using keys:
https://medium.com/@smaine.milianni/straightforward-symfony-4-best-practices-e6d1b3c0a9dd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/i18n.html#translation-keys):

> **Always use keys for translations instead of content strings.**
>
> Using keys simplifies the management of the translation files because
>   you can change the original contents without having to update all of
>   the translation files.
>
> Keys should always describe their purpose and not their location. For
>   example, if a form has a field with the label `Username`, then a nice
>   key would be `label.username`, not `edit_form.label.username`.

Using the key instead of text will often ends up avoiding errors when setting the key in the content, and show a much smaller content.

**Example**

```
<div>
    <span>{% trans %}Please enter the value of this input in order for the calculation to work{% endtrans %}</span>
    <label>{% trans %}Simple Input{% endtrans %}</label>
    <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

In this case, if you'd write `{% trans %}Simple input{% endtrans %}` somewhere else, then you'd have to manage another translation even though it is the same.

Sure, we could argue that you'd want to have uppercase / lowercase translation, but if using twig for example, you have some helping functions to handle the [lower](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/lower.html), [upper](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/upper.html) and [capitalize](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/capitalize.html).

**VS**

```
<div>
    <span>{% trans %}help_text.simple_input{% endtrans %}</span>
    <label>{% trans %}label.simple_input{% endtrans %}</label>
    <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Hooray for Symfony Best Practices!

Comment: @YetiCGN Yup! AFAIK, the best practices are decided for some reasons, so it kinda makes sense to follow them! :) (Unless, of course, something prevents you from using the best practices and there is no way around...)